# Returning object loses properties

Tags: c++, qt, deserialization

This is basically my main function :

```
void    GameObject::deserialize(QList<GameObject*> *list)
{
  QFile _file(_filename);
  if (!_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
  {
    qDebug() << "Couldn't open file to read";
    return;
  }
  QTextStream in(&_file);

  while (!in.atEnd())
  {
    QString currentline = in.readLine();
    if (currentline.startsWith("GameObject {"))
    {
      list->append(getGameObject(&in, currentline));
    }
  }
  _file.close();
}
```

It opens a file, and parses it for `GameObject`s.

The `getGameObject` *(cleaned up)* function is this one :

```
GameObject    *GameObject::getGameObject(QTextStream *in, QString current_line)
{
  GameObject *go = new GameObject();
  QList<GameObjectVariable*> govl;

  bool ok;
  while (!in->atEnd() && !current_line.startsWith("} end GameObject"))
  {
    current_line = in->readLine();
    if (current_line.startsWith("GameObjectVariable")) {
      GameObjectVariable *gov = this->getGameObjectVariable(in, current_line);
      govl.append(gov);
      go->setVariableList(&govl);
      qDebug() << QString("AR : Type As String of the returned object : ") + gov->getTypeAsAString();
      qDebug() << QString("AR : Type as number : ") + QString::number(gov->getType());
      if (gov->getType() == NUMBER_LIST) {
        qDebug() << "Number List";
        qDebug() << QString("Value as a string of the number list : ") + ((GameObjectVariableNumberList*)gov)->getValueAsAString();
      }
      else if (gov->getType() == STRING_LIST) {
        qDebug() << "String List";
        qDebug() << QString("Value as a string of the string list : ") + ((GameObjectVariableStringList*)gov)->getValueAsAString();
      }
      else if (gov->getType() == GAMEOBJECT) {
        qDebug() << "GameOBject";
        qDebug() << QString("Value as a string of the gameobject : ") + ((GameObjectVariableGameObject*)gov)->getValueAsAString();
      }
    }
  }
  return go;
}
```

This one basically is a big mess of `if`s, but it works, up to a point. The goal of this function is to read line by line, and return a gameobject filled with the read info. This is a weird format we use for the project though.

The last bunch of lines are Debug lines I've put in to try to understand where the problem was.

This is the other *(cleaned up)* function that's related :

```
GameObjectVariable* GameObject::getGameObjectVariable(QTextStream *in, QString current_line)
{
    GameObjectVariable *gov;
    bool ok;
    int type;
    QList<QString> ls;
    QList<int> ln;
    QList<GameObject*> lgo;


    while (!in->atEnd() && !current_line.startsWith("} end GameObjectVariable")) {
        current_line = in->readLine();
        if (current_line.startsWith("type: "))
        {
            type = current_line.right(current_line.size() - 5).toInt(&ok, 10);
        }
        else if (current_line.startsWith("value: ")) {
            if (current_line.startsWith("value: {"))
            {
                while (!in->atEnd() && !current_line.startsWith("} end value"))
                {
                    current_line = in->readLine();
                    if (!current_line.startsWith("} end value"))
                    {
                        if (type == GAMEOBJECT_LIST)
                        {
                            lgo.append(getGameObject(in, current_line));
                        }
                        else if (type == STRING_LIST)
                        {
                            ls.append(current_line);
                        }
                        else if (type == NUMBER_LIST)
                        {
                            ln.append(current_line.toInt(&ok, 10));
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (type == GAMEOBJECT_LIST)
                   ((GameObjectVariableGameObjectList*) gov)->setValue(&lgo);
                else if (type == STRING_LIST)
                    ((GameObjectVariableStringList*) gov)->setValue(&ls);
                else if (type == NUMBER_LIST)
                    ((GameObjectVariableNumberList*) gov)->setValue(&ln);
            }
        }
    }
    qDebug() << QString("BR : Get the type as string : ") + gov->getTypeAsAString();
    qDebug() << QString("BR : Get the type as number : ") + QString::number(gov->getType());
    qDebug() << QString("BR : get the value as string of the object : ") + gov->getValueAsAString();

    return gov;
}
```

This function reads the lines in the `GameObjectVariable` 'tag'. The type is a defined int that is macroed to the text type we use for the other `if` forest. 
Now this again works fine, except for when we have a list of values (the part that starts with `else if (current_line.startsWith("value: {"))`).

**The debug lines at the end of the function (the "BR :" ones) show the object properly filled, but the ones at the end of the `getGameObject` calling function (starting with "AR :") crash, because apparently the value is null.**

`GameObjectVariable` object is this one *(again, cleaned up)* :

```
class GameObjectVariable
{
public:
    GameObjectVariable(QString name, QList<int> idListEdit = QList<int>(), QList<int> idListView = QList<int>());

    // GETTERS
    QString                         getName()                                       {return this->name;}
    int                             getType()                                       {return this->type;}
    void                            *getValue()                                     {return this->value;}

    // SETTERS
    void                            setName(QString name)                           {this->name = name;}
    void                            setValue(void* value)                           {this->value = value;}

    QString                         getTypeAsAString();
    virtual QString                 getValueAsAString() = 0;

private:
    QString                         name;

protected:
    void                            *value;
    int                             type;
};
```

`getValueAsAString` is set as virtual because every type mentioned in the code above (like `GameObjectVariableStringList` overwrite this one with a return of their `value` with the correct type)

Finally, here is an example of file we try to deserialize :

```
GameObject {
name: Number 1
type: Test
GameObjectVariableStringList: {
type: 3
name: List String
value: {
String 1
String 2
} end value
} end GameObjectVariable
```

(`type: 3` corresponds to `STRING_LIST`)

The main problem is bolded.

Comment: aside: Many of those `if` blocks should be `else if`s, as unless the optimiser is really kind to you, you are making the compiler pointlessly check for things that you have already proven above cannot be true. Or just use `switch`/`case`, which also ensures you don't need to either call getters multiple times redundantly or cache the result in a temporary.

Comment: Anyway, it seems to me that you should be stepping through the code with a real debugger and identifying where things start to go sideways, instead of parodying a debugger using print statements. :P

Comment: @underscore_d indeed, changed them to `else if`s. Not solving the issue though :p

Answer (score 4):

## The problem

`getGameObjectVariable()`'s local variable `GameObjectVariable *gov` is an uninitialised pointer, which you suddenly cast to some other type and then start trying to call methods on.

How did you expect that to end? You are telling the compiler this: *Poke at random memory as if it holds an allocated, initialised object. Also, this object might have any of 3 different types.*

Seriously: What did you think was happening in that function, that it was somehow producing a usable object? I'm genuinely curious.

Anyway, for at least three reasons, this is malformed code that exhibits completely undefined behaviour:

- The pointer is uninitialised, so like any uninitialised variable, reading/dereferencing it is UB.
- No object is alive at the (invalid) address to which it points, but you call methods on it as if an object lives there; that is UB.
- Said methods then presumably start writing stuff to whatever arbitrary address you happened to end up at, with no permission, which is *lethal* UB.

(Also, even if there was valid memory to access and a valid object at it, casting the pointer to another type then using it is only valid if an instance of that other type was specifically allocated at that address - or some more-derived one, but then the C-style cast is (A) bad style and (B) potentially very dangerous if e.g. multiple and/or virtual inheritance are in play.)

Due to all this UB, anything can happen, or nothing might happen, or exactly what you want *just might* happen - but the code is fundamentally broken.

For example, as seems to have occurred here, the compiler might *coincidentally* act like there is a valid object while within the same function, but then you return that garbage pointer to `getGameObject()`, and it suddenly reveals that you fed it rubbish.

UB gives the compiler, and particularly its optimising layers, free reign to do whatever they want, chiefly because they are allowed to assume UB does not happen. So, e.g. they can assume there must be a valid object pointed to by `gov`, even if there blatantly isn't. That assumption gets lost after you return, though, for whatever reason.

Who knows? The precise reasons for the observed behaviour are pretty uninteresting to speculate about. You can produce assembly output if you really want to know why what happened happened.

## The (immediate) solution

But the key point is this: You need to replace this particular mess with proper, valid code - and *fast*. So, you need to assign a valid value to the pointer, by assigning it the address of a newly allocated object of whichever type is required. Only then do you have an address to which you are allowed access, with a living object at it, of the right type. It's then OK to create a cast pointer of the real derived type to call derived methods, but return a pointer-to-base for others to use.

## Conditionally calling methods, etc.

Also, those conditional casts and calls to `setValue()` look suspicious. Why not just make that a virtual method and let the compiler resolve the right variation? Generally, if you have some conditional construct deciding which method to call based on the real type... You should just use virtual functions. Most concern about their overhead is FUD, and most attempts to avoid that overhead are no more efficient to execute and much worse to read.

For instance, do you expect all users of any `GameObjectVariable` to repeat the same hoop-jumping exercise of checking what type it is and casting to the equivalent type of pointer to call the right (derived, hiding-not-overriding) version of `setValue()`? Hello, boilerplate spaghetti code, for no reason.

I think this points at more general bad patterns in your design. Rather than having huge functions that repeatedly have to check the type and do different things, with different lists depending on the type, etc. - why not simply check the type specified by the input line, and construct a new object of that type with, for example, the rest of the line as an argument, letting it create and populate whatever type of list and any other specific attributes it needs? Then you'll have tidy methods that do single things, not labyrinths that must constantly remind themselves what kind of object they're working with.

## Avoid `new`

Note that I said said to assign the pointer from "a newly allocated object", not *a `new`ly allocated object*... Most people should not ever need to use raw `new` or `delete` in C++, so you should return a `unique_ptr`, ideally from `std::make_unique<Foo>(args)`.

There is a fair exception if, as [hyde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1717300/hyde) points out in the comments, your new object is of a type that should have its lifetime managed by a parent object to which it is then added. Then `new` is OK - assuming there's no better way to phrase it, like I dunno, `make_floating_reference<Foo>(args)`. But, as hyde also said, that isn't the case for your `GameObjectVariable`, so a smart pointer is the way to go for that.

(Normally I would say you probably don't need dynamic allocation at all, but since you appear to need polymorphism and the objects clearly don't comprise a known set on the stack to which you could push non-owning pointers/reference-wrappers into the container, it seems that you do.)

Comment: About "avoid new", since this is Qt code: In Qt there usually are quite a lot of `new` used (but not `delete`) when creating `QObject` subclass instances, and this is fine. This is because these objects use parent-child mechanism and parents own their children and delete them on destruction etc (so having double ownership with a strong smart pointer is generally a bad idea).

Comment: Of course the question code does not use `QObject` subclass, so using a smart pointer is the way to go.

Comment: @hyde Fair enough, good clarification. Indeed, my choice `gtkmm` defaults to automatic duration, but allows delegating ownership to a parent by creating with `Gtk::manage(new SomeClass)`, thus granting the 'floating reference' behaviour that's default in GTK+, then sinking the reference by adding it to a container. I never used it before, but I've found it's handy for widgets I never need to use again, instead of e.g. having to declare them as class members if they're just implementation details. I wish `gtkmm` had a wrapper func so I didn't have to type `new`, i.e. could take my own advice :P

Comment: @downvoter: Do you have a point? Or are you just in the middle of a tantrum?